# Difference in plot edges with shading faceted vs. shading interp

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an issue about the plot of a 2D map with color bar. In my application, I have data with a size of map equal to 258x98.

If I plot these data with surf and `shading interp`, everything is good.

[image: Good map : with shading interp;]

But if I plot them with `shading faceted`, different rows at the upper horizontal part of map seem to be missing.

[image: Bad map : with shading faceted]

The upper border is not initially red like in the `shading interp;` version.

I found [a post](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/293702) which talks about this problem; it may come from `shading faceted` default behavior.

Could anyone confirm that the rows are missing when plotting? How can I fix it so that all boundaries data are plotted with `shading faceted`?

### MCVE

I tried to reproduce the issue with a simple example. Here's a simple Matlab script :

```
x_dim=256;
y_dim=96;
[X Y]=meshgrid(0:x_dim+1,0:y_dim+1);
Z = abs(X-x_dim/2).*abs(Y-y_dim/2);
Z(1:5,:)=x_dim*y_dim/2;
Z(end-4:end,:)=x_dim*y_dim/2;

surf(X,Y,Z);
view([0,0,1]);
hc=colorbar;
set(hc,'position',[0.932 0.3 0.02 0.6]);
xlim([0 x_dim+1]);
ylim([0 y_dim+1]);
xlabel('x domain');
ylabel('y domain');
%shading interp;
```

and the figure with `shading faceted` (which is default option) :

[image: plot with shading faceted]

You can see that upper red rectangle is less thick than the bottom one. With `shading interp;` as below, the difference is less visible, it may reproduce my issue, i.e at the first part of my question.

The figure with `shading interp;`

[image: plot with shading interp]

Comment: To confirming this behavior, it is necessary to have a [mcve]. You should try to reproduce this effect with toy data, and add your code for producing the figure with the toy data as an edit to this post before we can help you.

Comment: -@Cecillia you can have more informations in my **UPDATE 1**

Comment: Use annnother colormap pleaseee T.T

Comment: -@Ander Biguri do you mean other limits of colorbar ?

Comment: I don't really want to download and open a random data file. Can you reproduce the same result using toy Z data, for example, `Z = abs(Y-50);`?

Comment: the issue is not reproduced with your suggestion, the problem is on horizontal upper border with my data

Comment: until you have a verifiable example that is not shady , i will vote to close.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't understand why you say "until a verifiable example" : you have in my **UPDATE 1** part : 1*) the output file available on pastebin with its link (named output.dat), 2*) the Matlab script that I use for plotting this output.dat file and 3*) I have put the 2 images that I produce with the Matlab script and which illustrates my issue, what do you want more ?

Comment: What MadPhysicist means is that we don't want to download a random data file off Stack Overflow. If your problem were easy to reproduce using toy data (that's the minimal part of [mcve]), we would be happy to help. If my example doesn't work, you need to find one that does. Maybe a 10x10 sub matrix of your real data would work. Then you can paste the values directly into your question. Or maybe a random matrix would work. Try out a few different, easily constructible toy data sources. If you cannot reproduce the problem with another data source, then the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: -@MadPhysicist, -@Cecilia I tried to do a simple example to reproduce the issue, you can see it on **UPDATE 2**, regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I did was to zoom in to check what the rendering looked like close up.

### Zoom of top of figure

```
subplot(1,2,1);
surf(X,Y,Z);
view([0,0,1]);
colorbar;
xlim([0,1])
ylim([y_dim-5, y_dim-2])
title('shading faceted');

subplot(1,2,2);
surf(X,Y,Z);
view([0,0,1]);
colorbar;
xlim([0,1])
ylim([y_dim-5, y_dim-2])
shading interp
title('shading interp');
```

[image: Zoom to top]

What you can see is that the color bleed that you are seeing happens in between grid lines. The values of Z are defined at integer intervals. The extended red in the interpolated rendering happens in the interval between integer grid lines.

The faceted version shows one value for the whole interval, so which value does it pick? The value at the lower or higher integer grid line? Using the data cursor, or by examining matrix values (i.e. `display(Z(93,1))`), we can see that the color of the facet is determined by the value at the lower edge.

The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shading.html) confirms this behavior:

> `shading flat` each mesh line segment and face has a constant color
>   determined by the color value at the endpoint of the segment or the
>   corner of the face that has the smallest index or indices.
>
> `shading faceted` flat shading with superimposed black mesh lines.
>   This is the default shading mode.

So faceted shading, like flat shading, starts with the color value at the endpoint of the facet with the smallest index or grid line.

Where as,

> `shading interp` varies the color in each line segment and face by
>   interpolating the colormap index or true color value across the line
>   or face.

That's why the bottom of the figure has a wider red band in the `shading faceted` setting, because the lower index gridline determines the color of the facet.

### Zoom of bottom of figure

```
subplot(1,2,1);
surf(X,Y,Z);
view([0,0,1]);
colorbar;
xlim([0,1])
ylim([3,6])
title('shading faceted');

subplot(1,2,2);
surf(X,Y,Z);
view([0,0,1]);
colorbar;
xlim([0,1])
ylim([3,6])
shading interp
title('shading interp');
```

[image: Zoom to bottom]

Since this is the documented, as intended behavior of `shading faceted`. You have to think outside of the box to get the rendering you want.

### Solution 1 : imagesc

If you just want to plot the top (`view([0,0,1]`) of your surface, use `imagesc(Z)`. This will plot each element in Z as a pixel, instead of placing the pixels in-between Z elements. The overall appearance is similar to `shading faceted`, but the indices are shifted to the middle of the pixel. For example,

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(0:2, 0:2);
Z = magic(3);

figure;
colormap('jet');

subplot(1, 3 ,1);
imagesc(Z);
axis xy
yticklabels({'0', '1', '2'})
yticks(1:3)
xticklabels({'0', '1', '2'})
xticks(1:3)
title('imagesc(Z)');

subplot(1,3,2);
surf(X, Y, Z);
shading faceted;
view([0,0,1]);
yticks(0:3)
xticks(0:3)
title('surf(X, Y, Z); shading faceted;');

subplot(1,3,3);
surf(X, Y, Z);
shading interp;
view([0,0,1]);
yticks(0:3)
xticks(0:3)
title('surf(X, Y, Z); shading interp;');
```

[image: Rendering comparison for top view using imagesc, shading faceted and shading interp]

You can see that the edge values are better rendered from the "bird's eye view perspective" using `imagesc` than using `shading faceted`.

Honestly though, from any other perspective, the `shading interp` just makes more intuitive sense. Here's the same surface as above rotated.

[image: Comparison of shading interp and faceted on rotated surface]

You can see that high points and low points are more intuitively colored with `shading interp`.

### Solution 2: Add another row and column

If you really need to use `shading faceted` for some reason. You can trick the visualization by adding another row and column to your data. From the top, it will look the way you want.  **Caveat: This will change the shape of the surface**

First make the X,Y grid larger, and duplicate the last row and column of Z

```
[X_extend, Y_extend] = meshgrid(0:3, 0:3);
Z_extend = [Z, Z(:, end);];
Z_extend = [Z_extend; Z_extend(end, :)];
```

Here's the `shading faceted` plot, both from above and slightly rotated.

[image: <code>shading faceted</code> with extended grid]

The above view is what we wanted, but in the rotated view the surface has changed. This rotation is similar to the one in the previous picture, but you can see the shape of the duplicated rows and columns has changed the edge of the surface by adding a rectangular facet on every edge along that side.

**Only use this method if the 3D shape of the edge is unimportant**

Comment: So, what's the solution to make the two horizontal red bars have the same width when plotting ?

Comment: @youpilat13 I've added 2 possible solutions.